# Why does my gradient descent optimizer blow up after getting close to a solution?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent

I'm trying to run through a simple linear regression example in Tensorflow, and it appears that the training algorithm is converging to a solution, but once it gets close to the solution, it starts bouncing around and eventually blows up.

I'm passing data for a `y = 2x` line, so the gradient descent optimizer should be able to easily converge to a solution.

```
import tensorflow as tf

M = tf.Variable([0.4], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-0.4], dtype=tf.float32)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

linear_model = M * x + b

error = linear_model - y
loss = tf.square(error)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(100):
        sess.run(optimizer, {x: i, y: 2 * i})
        print(sess.run([M, b]))
```

Here's the result.  I circled the portion where it gets close to a solution.  Why does the gradient descent break once it gets close to the solution, or is there's something that I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code feeds the training data one at a time for only one epoch. This corresponds to stochastic gradient descent, where the loss value tends to fluctuate more frequently than batch and mini-batch gradient descent during training. Moreover, since the data is fed in an increasing order of `x`, the gradient value also increases along with `x`. That is why you see larger fluctuations in the later part of an epoch.

Comment: Thank you.  I updated the code to use an array of numbers in each iteration, and now it's converging to the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the learning rate is too high; try lowering it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you have chosen a high learning rate. You can use grid search and find the optimal learning rate, then fit data using the optimal learning rate.